# Pesquisar por Raio de abrangência

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou programando um site e na busca avançada tem a opção do usuário fazer uma busca para encontrar locais próximos a cidade que ele está.

Tenho todas os estados e cidades cadastrados no banco.

Mas, não faço ideia de como fazer o sistema saber que um determinado local fica a 10 km daquele ponto.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz para saber onde iniciar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Então, o ideal é você salvar a latitude e longitude dos locais que serão salvos no banco. Depois, para calcular a distância entre dois pontos existem várias fórmulas. 
Nesse link tem algumas fórmulas que você pode usar: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Eu tenho usado a [Spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines). Segue a função que uso, em php.

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {
  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  
cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}
```

Recebendo como entrada, a latitude e longitude de cada ponto e um char "N" para indicar que o retorno é em milhas ou "K" para indicar que o retorno é em metros.

Se você for trabalhar com muitos locais, aconselho à dar uma procurada em uma forma mais eficiente de armazenar as localidades, para não ter que percorrer todos os pontos no banco. Algo tipo, cidades próximas ou mesmo estados próximos.

Comment: Terei que salvar as coordenadas no banco de dados para realizar as comparações com essa função aí, certo? vou testar e retorno com os resultados.

Comment: Agora me me explicar como eu utilizo?

Comment: Então, se você tiver as posições, é só entrar com a latitude e longitude do usuário e com a latitude e longitude de um dos locais do banco, a última variável o $unit, você entra com a letra "K", o retorno vai ser a distância entre o usuário o o local escolhido.